# Why does vue.js report 404 route in production, but not development?

Tags: vue.js, nginx

I'm new to Vue.js but can anyone explain to me why the routes would not work as intended?

In development mode locally there is no issue, but when I deploy to a server is when the issue arises. Running `npm run serve` I can visit `auth/login`, but after `npm run build` the server returns a 404 on `auth/login`. The server is a Digitial Ocean Ubuntu machine set as a git remote with hooks to auto build and serve `dist` if that matters.

I get a 404 when going to https://example.com/auth/login but navigating to https://example.com/address-records works just fine. It seems as if only something that is more than a single `/` deep returns a 404.

Here is the router code

```
let router = new Router({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "home",
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: "/auth/login",
      name: "Login",
      component: Login
    },
    {
      path: "/address-records",
      name: "Address",
      component: Address
    }
  ]
});
```

Is there something special I need to be doing with Nginx? I have it setup with similar searched questions.

```
 location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
 }
 location @rewrites {
         rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.html last;
      }

 location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
         # Some basic cache-control for static files to be sent to the browser
         expires max;
         add_header Pragma public;
         add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
  }
```